# Manipulate the output of <xsl:apply-templates>

Tags: xslt, string

How do I string manipulation on the output of `<xsl:apply-templates>`?

I need to escape quotes etc as it's finally being passed to a JavaScript variable.

Comment: Please provide some sample code to show what you are trying and explain more clearly what is not working. That way, we can try to provide some assistance.

Comment: The expected processing of the sting is something not explained at all in your question. Please submit another question asking exactly this. Provide a good example of the input (XML document or just a string) and the wanted output, with explanation about the requirements on the processing.

Answer (score 2):

The nice and clean approach would be to change your XSLT so that it's output does not need any additional manipulation.

If your call to `<xsl:apply-templates>` produces a string that must be manipulated for some reason, you would need to capture it in a variable first:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="temp-manipulated">
  <xsl:call-template name="do-some-string-mainpulation">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$temp" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$temp-manipulated" />
```

Alternatively, you can integrate the `<xsl:apply-templates>` into the `<xsl:with-param>`, wich would spare you one step:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:call-template name="do-some-string-mainpulation">
    <xsl:with-param name="string">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$temp" />
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I write out 
<xsl:call-template name="do-some-string-mainpulation">
to escape quotes, new lines since it will be passed to Javascript eventually.

Comment: @Iris This is something not explained at all in your question. Please submit another question asking exactly this. Provide a good example of the input (XML document or just a string) and the wanted output, with explanation about the requirements on the processing.

Comment: @Iris: What prevents you from taking the "nice and clean" route I talked about? I should think this is going to be easier than writing a string manipulation routine.

Comment: The issue I am having is <xsl:variable name="temp"><xsl:apply-templates select="node/nodeset"/></xsl:variable>
is empty for when node contains images and other tags. it works fine for plain text.

Comment: @Iris: There is no way to help you unless you provide a minimal (!) sample of your code that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Capture in a variable, then manipulate the value to create the output:

```
<xsl:variable name='temp'>
  <xsl:apply-templates ...>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select='expression involving $temp' />
```