# How do I replace quotes in XSLT with their HTML entities?

Tags: string, xslt

This is related to my previous question -" [Manipulate the output of <xsl:apply-templates>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778120/manipulate-the-output-of-xslapply-templates)".
I want to ask about the specific problem I am looking to address.
How do I replace quotes in XSLT with their HTML entities. I want to eventually pass it to Javascript variable with special characters escaped.

Comment: Could you give an EXAMPLE, P L E A SE  !!!

Comment: Javascript does not depend on "HTML entities", what do you need them for? Most probably they are not really needed.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the Google code project [xml2json-xslt](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/), especially the [xml2js.xslt](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/source/browse/trunk/xml2js.xslt) template. Perhaps your answer lies in there.